# OpenStreetMap (OSM) heatmap

Tags: openstreetmap

Has anyone used any of the following heat-map api/scritpts for OpenStreetMap:

1. Bjoern Hoehrmann's OpenLayers Heatmap Layer: http://www.websitedev.de/temp/openlayers-heatmap-layer.html
2. Heatmap by Patrick Wied: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/

I am looking for a free heatmap api that can be used in a production environment (a few thousand hits per day), so, if any one has used any of the above in a high visitor number environment, please share your experiences; otherwise please let me know if you are aware of any other free scripts for OSM heatmap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never used them, but you could try:

- https://github.com/fredj/openlayers-heatmap
- https://github.com/sunng87/heatcanvas